# Addition formula to increment each cell in range by $2

Tags: function, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, vba

I have a spreadsheet with roughly 750 part numbers and costs on it. I need to add $2 to each cost (not total the whole column). The range would be something like D1:D628 and I've tried using =SUM but either I'm doing it wrong or it isn't possible.

I initially tried `=SUM(D1:D628+2)` and got a circular reference warning, I've tried variations of the formula and keep getting errors even after removing the circular reference. I also tried the following VBA module insert:

```
Sub Add2Formula()
' Add 2

For Each c In Selection
c.Activate
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "= " & ActiveCell.Formula & "+2" 
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: `=D1+2` in `E1` and drag/corner-click to fill downwards?

Comment: Hi Roy. You should look up how to autofill. It is one of the most basic and useful features of excel. I would also recommend that you post future questions on Superuser http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel - until you gain a better understanding of excel. - as they will be more likely to explain beginning concepts to a new excel user.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add 2 to a range of numbers (not formulas) then

enter the number 2 in a blank cell somewhere
copy it
Select the cells you want to add 2 to, and then select paste special, choose ADD as the operation option.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula should work

`{=SUM(D1:D628+2)}`

Leave out the curly braces but press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to enter the function (rather than just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>)

EDIT: explanation

by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> excel treats the formula as an array, and loops through each cell individually adding 2 and then summing

Comment: This works, however it totals the entire column and I need it to add 2 to each individual cost in each cell. Above was suggested I use autofill but I'm looking at MS support on that right now and not seeing how that would be helpful.

Comment: It sounds like you should create a new column as @Alex K suggested? You can also put "2" into an unused cell, copy it, select all of your values in column D and paste special with the operation: add

Comment: That is actually what I am doing and will just total the two columns and right autofill. I was looking for a way to macro or formula embed but it apparently doesn't exist - at least not for what I am wanting to do.